# Python prints the same data multiple times

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have got a data from twitter and now manipulating it.
I am trying to get all texts of the tweets into one list of strings.

The data contains column "content" that shows the text of the tweet. I want to get all texts into one list or array for further analysis.

Here is my code:

```
data= []

for i in range(len(data)):
    if data['content'] is not None:
        data.append(data['content'])
data
```

For some reasons Python prints the result for many times (the size of data). I believe I am doing something wrong with the for loop. I just want to print the list once.

Thank you for help!

Comment: I didn't get your logic could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think that json file contains that much data

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ yes, my json file contains information of 20k tweets. I want to get all texts onto one list so I can get the hashtags after. When I run my code it prints the result I want for 20k times (so 20k lists of lists). I want just one:)

Comment: I got it now I will post soln

Comment: What is the structure of your json? Can you provide some sample?

Comment: @IoaTzimas I have added the screenshot of my data

Answer (score 3):

Try to save your column directly to list, like below:

```
result=list(tweets_data['content'])
```

Comment: Why? tweets_data is a dataframe. It should work

Comment: Great! @Alex don't forget to accept/upvote answers. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
tweets_data = pd.read_json('twitter.json', lines=True)

tweet_text = []

for data in tweets_data: # changed you are just iterating over length that wrong way
    data=json.loads(data)
    if data['content'] is not None:
        tweet_text.append(data['content'])
tweet_text
```

Even you can use list comprehension

```
tweet_text = [json.loads(data)['content'] for data in tweets_data if data]
print(tweet_text)
```

You can iterate over the objects :)

Comment: ----> 4     if data['content'] is not None: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: you shoud load it to json

Comment: I hope now it should work if not just tell me

Comment: what do you mean by load it to json? The list comprehension also doesn't work

Comment: yaa those contents are in strings rgt? but its a dictionary so you should convert it to dictionary/json